# Rotate and preserve 3d not working

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transforms

The animation is working but the #sun rotate not with preserve 3d if stop the animation the rotate and preserve 3d work. How to make to work the animation and all rotations ?

Html:

```
<div class="holder">
     <div class="system">
         <img src="image/sun.png"class="objects" id="sun">
    </div></div>
```

Css:

```
.holder{width:40%;height:50%;margin-left:10%;margin-top:10%;position:relative;
        -ms-transform:rotateX(75deg);
     -moz-transform:rotateX(75deg);
     -webkit-transform:rotateX(75deg);
         -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
        }
.system{
    position:relative;height:100%;width:100%;   
    -webkit-animation: orbit 5s linear infinite;
-moz-animation: orbit 5s linear infinite;
    animation: orbit 5s linear infinite;
}
#sun{transform:rotateX(75deg);width:8%;height:10%;position:relative;
-ms-transform:rotateX(75deg);
     -moz-transform:rotateX(75deg);
     -webkit-transform:rotateX(75deg);
}
@-webkit-keyframes orbit {
          from {
            -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg);
          }

          to {
            -webkit-transform: rotateZ(360deg);
          }
        }
```

Comment: keep an habit to read the titles if you don't understand iconic presentation, you blockquoted your code instead of highlight it with a syntax highlighter

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you work with transformation like thse, I think you need to have a perspective on your main div.

like:

```
body{
-webkit-perspective: 500px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
perspective: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Demo : http://codepen.io/Alesso05/pen/vEdfJ

This is not run:

```
#holder{
         -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
        }
        #sun{
             transform:rotateX(75deg);
-ms-transform:rotateX(75deg);
     -moz-transform:rotateX(75deg);
     -webkit-transform:rotateX(75deg) ;
}
```